# How to fit three gaussian peaks in python?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to fit the three peaks using python. I'm able to fit the first peak, but having problem in converging the fitting function to the next two peaks. Can someone please help me?

I guess there is some problem with the initial guesses!

Here is the code and figure:

```py
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'

""" Fitting Function"""
def _2gauss(x, amp1, cen1, sigma1, amp2, cen2, sigma2):
    return amp1*(1/(sigma1*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x-cen1)/sigma1)**2))) + \
    amp2*(1/(sigma2*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x-cen2)/sigma2)**2)))+ \
    amp3*(1/(sigma3*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x-cen3)/sigma3)**2))) 
data_12 = np.loadtxt("ExcitationA.txt", skiprows=30, dtype=np.float64)
xData, yData = np.hsplit(data_12,2)
x = xData[:,0]
y = yData[:,0]
n = len(x)
amp1 = 400
sigma1 = 10
cen1 = 400

amp2 = 400
sigma2 = 5
cen2 = 400

amp3 = 340
sigma3 = 6
cen3 = 340
popt, pcov = curve_fit(_2gauss, x, y, p0= [amp1, cen1, sigma1, amp2, cen2, sigma2])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.plot(x, y, 'b', markersize=1, label="12°C")
ax.plot(x, _2gauss(x, *popt), markersize='1',label="Fit function", linewidth=4, color='purple')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: _2gauss function is missing amp3, sigma3, cen3. Can it caculate without those parameter, also "ExcitationA.txt" is missing? Please provide a working code snipet so others can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are 9 parameters, to obtain a good fit, the initial values for those parameters should be close.  An idea is to experiment drawing

```py
p0 = [amp1, cen1, sigma1, amp2, cen2, sigma2, amp3, cen3, sigma3]
ax.plot(x, _2gauss(x, *p0))
```

until the parameters are more or less equal. In this example, it is important that the centers `cen1`, `cen2` and `cen3` are close to the observed local maxima (340, 355, 375).

Once you have reasonable initial values, you can start the fit. Also note that in the originally posted example code `amp3, cen3, sigma3` are missing as parameters to the function `_2gauss`.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gauss_1(x, amp1, cen1, sigma1):
    return amp1 * (1 / (sigma1 * (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))) * (np.exp((-1.0 / 2.0) * (((x - cen1) / sigma1) ** 2)))

def gauss_3(x, amp1, cen1, sigma1, amp2, cen2, sigma2, amp3, cen3, sigma3):
    """ Fitting Function"""
    return amp1 * (1 / (sigma1 * (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))) * (np.exp((-1.0 / 2.0) * (((x - cen1) / sigma1) ** 2))) + \
           amp2 * (1 / (sigma2 * (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))) * (np.exp((-1.0 / 2.0) * (((x - cen2) / sigma2) ** 2))) + \
           amp3 * (1 / (sigma3 * (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))) * (np.exp((-1.0 / 2.0) * (((x - cen3) / sigma3) ** 2)))

x = np.array([300.24, 301.4, 302.56, 303.72, 304.88, 306.04, 307.2, 308.36, 309.51, 310.67, 311.83, 312.99, 314.04, 314.93, 315.77, 316.56, 317.3, 318.03, 318.77, 319.5, 320.23, 321.02, 321.86, 325.76, 326.6, 327.54, 328.49, 329.17, 329.69, 330.27, 330.84, 331.16, 335.85, 336.37, 337.05, 337.79, 339.58, 341.43, 342.42, 343.87, 345.01, 346.07, 346.91, 347.53, 348.06, 348.53, 348.89, 351.33, 351.8, 352.11, 352.42, 352.75, 353.15, 353.6, 354.04, 354.36, 354.87, 355.77, 356.72, 357.36, 357.83, 358.25, 358.69, 358.96, 359.29, 359.61, 359.93, 360.25, 360.58, 360.86, 361.16, 361.39, 361.61, 361.96, 362.3, 362.62, 363.0, 363.43, 363.94, 364.55, 365.18, 366.14, 367.3, 368.19, 368.82, 369.45, 370.03, 371.07, 371.54, 371.96, 372.31, 372.69, 373.11, 373.52, 373.99, 374.67, 375.68, 376.58, 377.11, 377.54, 377.81, 378.09, 378.4, 378.71, 378.94, 379.08, 379.3, 379.52, 379.73, 379.95, 380.17, 380.34, 380.61, 380.82, 380.99, 381.22, 381.44, 381.66, 381.88, 382.1, 382.32, 382.53, 382.75, 382.97, 383.24, 383.74, 384.0, 384.28, 384.49, 384.71, 384.92, 385.14, 385.36, 385.58, 385.9, 386.26, 386.6, 386.92, 387.29, 387.71, 388.31, 388.84, 389.53, 390.38, 391.39, 392.56, 393.72, 394.89, 396.05, 397.22, 397.69, 398.38, 398.86, 399.54, 400.02, 400.71, 401.18, 401.87, 402.34, 403.03, 403.19, 404.19, 405.36, 406.52, 407.68, 408.84, 410.01, 411.17, 412.33, 413.49, 414.65, 415.81, 416.98, 417.61])
y = np.array([3.6790e-01, 4.1930e-01, 4.6530e-01, 5.1130e-01, 5.6300e-01, 6.1750e-01, 6.6780e-01, 7.2950e-01, 7.8830e-01, 8.4960e-01, 9.0950e-01, 9.6660e-01, 1.0463e+00, 1.1324e+00, 1.2241e+00, 1.3026e+00, 1.3889e+00, 1.4780e+00, 1.5598e+00, 1.6432e+00, 1.7318e+00, 1.8256e+00, 1.9050e+00, 2.1595e+00, 2.2477e+00, 2.3343e+00, 2.4183e+00, 2.5115e+00, 2.5970e+00, 2.6825e+00, 2.7657e+00, 2.8198e+00, 3.8983e+00, 3.9956e+00, 4.0846e+00, 4.1526e+00, 4.2787e+00, 4.2256e+00, 4.2412e+00, 4.2731e+00, 4.3265e+00, 4.4073e+00, 4.4905e+00, 4.5831e+00, 4.6717e+00, 4.7660e+00, 4.8395e+00, 5.6288e+00, 5.7239e+00, 5.8141e+00, 5.9076e+00, 6.0026e+00, 6.1034e+00, 6.2157e+00, 6.3235e+00, 6.4114e+00, 6.5063e+00, 6.5709e+00, 6.5175e+00, 6.4349e+00, 6.3479e+00, 6.2638e+00, 6.2102e+00, 6.0616e+00, 5.9664e+00, 5.8697e+00, 5.7625e+00, 5.6546e+00, 5.5494e+00, 5.4404e+00, 5.3384e+00, 5.2396e+00, 5.1462e+00, 5.0412e+00, 4.9467e+00, 4.8592e+00, 4.7655e+00, 4.6709e+00, 4.5807e+00, 4.4803e+00, 4.3947e+00, 4.3347e+00, 4.3286e+00, 4.3918e+00, 4.4800e+00, 4.5637e+00, 4.6489e+00, 4.8435e+00, 4.9454e+00, 5.0396e+00, 5.1258e+00, 5.2200e+00, 5.3082e+00, 5.3945e+00, 5.4874e+00, 5.5974e+00, 5.6396e+00, 5.5880e+00, 5.4984e+00, 5.4082e+00, 5.3213e+00, 5.2270e+00, 5.1271e+00, 5.0247e+00, 4.9258e+00, 4.8324e+00, 4.7317e+00, 4.6336e+00, 4.5323e+00, 4.4258e+00, 4.3166e+00, 4.2152e+00, 4.1011e+00, 3.9754e+00, 3.8646e+00, 3.7401e+00, 3.6061e+00, 3.4715e+00, 3.3381e+00, 3.2120e+00, 3.0865e+00, 2.9610e+00, 2.8361e+00, 2.7126e+00, 2.6289e+00, 2.2796e+00, 2.1818e+00, 2.0747e+00, 1.9805e+00, 1.8864e+00, 1.7942e+00, 1.7080e+00, 1.6236e+00, 1.5279e+00, 1.4145e+00, 1.2931e+00, 1.1805e+00, 1.0785e+00, 9.8490e-01, 8.9590e-01, 7.9850e-01, 7.0670e-01, 6.2110e-01, 5.2990e-01, 4.4250e-01, 3.7360e-01, 3.1090e-01, 2.5880e-01, 2.0680e-01, 1.6760e-01, 1.4570e-01, 1.2690e-01, 1.1060e-01, 9.5900e-02, 9.0600e-02, 8.0600e-02, 7.0600e-02, 5.8100e-02, 4.4200e-02, 4.4200e-02, 4.4200e-02, 4.1400e-02, 3.4900e-02, 2.4200e-02, 1.9600e-02, 1.5300e-02, 1.5000e-02, 1.1800e-02, 1.3200e-02, 7.8000e-03, 5.0000e-03, 1.0000e-02, 4.6000e-03, 0.0])
amp1 = 100
sigma1 = 9
cen1 = 375
amp2 = 100
sigma2 = 7
cen2 = 355
amp3 = 100
sigma3 = 10
cen3 = 340
p0 = [amp1, cen1, sigma1, amp2, cen2, sigma2, amp3, cen3, sigma3]
y0 = gauss_3(x, *p0)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(gauss_3, x, y, p0=p0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.plot(x, y, 'b', label="given curve")
ax.plot(x, y0, 'g', ls=':', label="initial fit params")
ax.plot(x, gauss_3(x, *popt), ls=':', label="Fit function", linewidth=4, color='purple')
for i, (a, c, s )in enumerate( popt.reshape(-1, 3)):
    ax.plot(x, gauss_1(x, a, c, s), ls='-', label=f"gauss {i+1}", linewidth=1, color='crimson')
ax.legend()
ax.autoscale(axis='x', tight=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]