# scipy.optimize.curve_fit, parameters all return with 1

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to fit my data.

```
params = curve_fit(gauss2, A, B)

def gauss2(x, a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2):
    return a1*np.exp(-((x-b1)/c1)**2) + a2*np.exp(-((x-b2)/c2)**2)
```

As A and B are quite big numbers(`np.mean(A)=38956`, `np.mean(B)=3112`), `params` here are 1. Is there solution for my problem?

Comment: You may help `curve_fit` by providing the estimated initial values of the parameters.

Comment: [How to fit three gaussian peaks in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63626500/how-to-fit-three-gaussian-peaks-in-python/63648954#63648954) might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your `curve_fit` result by providing initial guess and parameter boundaries.

```py
curve_fit(gauss2, A, B, 
       p0=(a0, b0, c0, a0, b0, c0), # your inital guess for these parameters
       bounds=[
        (a1, b1, c1, a1, b1, c1), # lower bound for parameters
        (a2, b2, c2, a2, b2, c2) # upper bound for parameters
       ] )
```

Comment: Can I intial p0 randomly?

Comment: @jasonshu Yes, you can. However, you need to make sure p0 is between the upper and lower bounds you provided. I will use the mean value of upper and lower bounds if I don't have better guess.